# ELO ECM Suite 20

Tags: sql-server, windows, server, sql-update, ecm

I use ELO 11 Professional and I wanna update it to ELO ECM Suite 20.
Did someone use to work with ELO and maybe can give me some tips how to update it? I found some information in google how to Update but I wanna avoid small mistakes.
Thank you very much
Best Wishes, Oleg

Answer (score 2):

We are working with ELO, currently with version 12. Our business partner told us to not update to version 20 because of many bugs. So we trust in our partner and wait for ELO21.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this via the All-In-One Client.
And you need a license key for it.

It would be advisable to switch to 20 or 21 because the LTS for 12 will end soon.